# Best way to save timestamp for new or modified records in custom component

Tags: php, joomla-4.x, custom-component, mysql, javascript

In my custom component I have two database tables for items in my component with the standard 'created' and 'modified' datetime columns to contain timestamps when those items are created or modified.

I initially assumed that the easiest way to do this was via the database, setting the default value for 'created' as current_timestamp and the 'modified' column to be set with current_timestamp on update. This worked fine on my local install (XAMPP) which is on MariaDB 10.4.28, but when I updated my component on my Siteground test site which uses MySQL 5.7.44 it throws an error. Datetime columns don't seem to like the current_timestamp value. One possible fix that I saw suggested was to change datetime to timestamp but it made no difference.

I then looked at how core Joomla tables with 'created' and 'modified' columns are set up and they don't use current_timestamp to automatically populate. It looks as if I need to get my code to set these values instead.

That being the case, I added 'created' and 'modified' to my form XML and brought them them into my edit.php template file. I could set the timestamp value when I first open a new or existing item, but ideally I'd like to do it immediately prior to saving. Is there a javascript event that I can watch for when the Save button is clicked that I can make use of? If not, is it a case of extending the FormController Save PHP function and setting the values there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Banners component as an example you can see the way that it handles the empty date fields in the `..\administrator\components\com_banners\src\Table\BannerTable.php` `check()` method.

The `check()` method is called by the `save()` method of the `..\libraries\src\Table\Table.php`. The `save()` method calls `bind()`, `check()`, `store()` and `checkIn()` methods.

In the Model for your Form you would have it call the `save()` method found in AdminModel or your own Table object.

```
/**
* Overloaded check function
*
* @return  boolean
*
             * @see     Table::check
* @since   1.5
*/
public function check()
{
...
    // Set created date if not set.
    if (!(int) $this->created) {
    $this->created = Factory::getDate()->toSql();
    }
    ...
    // Set modified to created if not set
    if (!$this->modified) {
    $this->modified = $this->created;
    }
            
    // Set modified_by to created_by if not set
    if (empty($this->modified_by)) {
    $this->modified_by = $this->created_by;
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks - that's perfect. All working nicely now :)

Answer (score 1):

Do your database tables have associated classes which extend the Joomla Table class?

If so, you can set these attributes in a store() function, overriding Table::store(). They'll then be set just before saving to the database.

You can see how com_content does this by looking at libraries/src/Table/Content.php

Comment: Thanks Robbie - I've gone with setting the timestamps in the check function as per Irata's reply, but as I haven't really looked at my table classes since setting them up when I first started building my component it's been a good exercise to get more familiar with them. It's opened up a few ways where I can now improve some of the other code I've written.